# WPF update ItemSource from different thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading

SO i have main form and second form that hold `ListView`:

```
public partial class LoggerForm : MetroWindow
{
    public LoggerForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListView Name="lvLogger"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(list:LogHelper.LogEntries)}"
          Background="#181818"
          Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateTime}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Index" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Index}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Level" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Level}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Source" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Source}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Message" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Message}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Log object:

```
public class LogEntry
{
    public string DateTime { get; set; }

    public int Index { get; set; }

    public string Source{ get; set; }

    public Level Level { get; set; }        

    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

List of my Log object:

```
public static class LogHelper
{
    public static ObservableCollection<LogEntry> LogEntries { get; set; }
    public static void AddLog(Level level, string message, string source)
    {
        LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry()
        {
            DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff"),
            Index = LogEntries.Count + 1,
            Level = level,
            Source = source,
            Message = message
        };

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            LogEntries.Add(logEntry);
        }));            
    }
}
```

And this is how i am create new `Log`:

`LogHelper.AddLog(Level.Info, "My message", $"{ GetType().Name }\\{ MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name }")`;

So i have another `class` that do its `work` and Using `Task` with different `thread` and in this case i cannot see its messages in my `ListView` although i try to use this way:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    LogEntries.Add(logEntry);
}));
```

Comment: If the data is coming into your collection then you probably just need to implement a INotifyPropertyChanged on your xaml and add the following to your C# class - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification

Comment: LogEntries is an observablecollection. He should implement inotifypropertchanged on any viewmodel to obviate the risk of memory leaks but observablecollection raises events when an item is added ( + deleted or changed ).

Comment: Hey Mark.  Did you definitely get rid of all that extra threading stuff that was creating multiple dispatchers? In your output window. No binding errors?